# How to disable jdbc logs

Tags: spring

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olw5a.png)

[log4j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie7Kb.png)

I am using STS4, Legacy project.
How to disable jdbc logs.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the application.properties

```
logging.level.jdbc.resultset=NONE
```